# Where is attr_accessor defined?

Tags: ruby

Currently working on a ruby minifier using [Ripper](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html)'s `lex()` method. However currently `attr_accessor` is defined as an identifier... I assume because it's a method.

Where is `attr_accessor` defined? If I know where it's defined I can easily make exceptions for methods like it.

Comment: That's just a method name, and while a common one, there shouldn't be any special syntax requirements for handling it. A lot of Ruby syntax highlighters treat it as special, though, which is perhaps why your lexer does.

Comment: @tadman well no that's the problem. The lexer didn't treat it as special and thus my minifier was turning `class A; attr_accessor :b; end` into `class A; x1 :b; end` which literally wouldn't work. So I needed to alter it to make `attr_accessor` and all other 'special methods' not minifying method names.

Comment: That seems like a broken way to minify, as `attr_accessor` is pretty important and can't just be omitted.

Comment: Ruby's not necessarily the best to try and minify, and I'm not even sure why you'd want to. There's a lot of fussy syntax rules you're going to run afoul of if you're not super careful. A lot of code is also wildly dynamic which breaks most efforts to minify, a problem that JavaScript (e.g. Angular) has clunky ways of trying to prevent when renaming function arguments and variables that have specific and important names.

Comment: `attr_accessor` is pretty important, indeed, thus minifcation there was prevented in this instance, and similarly with method names and so on. And indeed, I've ran into several issues already, but i'm gradually ironing out these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined in the `Module` class. [(Documentation Link)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)

EDIT: 
Just to make the answer more complete, it is a **private** method of the `Module` class, which means you cannot call it with a receiver, need to have the class opened to use it (or using some hack like `send` or `eval`):

```
class MyClassOrModule
  attr_accessor :foobar
end
```

You cannot invoke it as `MyClassOrModule.attr_accessor`. As you already discovered in our comments below, `Module.private_instance_methods` will show its presence.

Comment: How come `Module.methods.include? :attr_accessor #=> false`?

Comment: Ah... it's in `Module.private_instance_methods` instead it seems.

Comment: Yeah, was just typing that it was private when you replied. :)

Comment: Newer versions of Ruby are better at identifying what methods are public and private. Older ones would list the method as being present but when you called it you would find out you couldn't.

Comment: Note that `Module.methods` does *not* give you the methods that are defined in `Module`, rather it gives you the methods that `Module` *responds to*, i.e. the ones that are defined in `Module`'s *class*, not in `Module` itself. Now, in this *particular* case, that would actually *accidentally* work, because the class of `Module` is `Class`, which is a subclass of `Module` and thus `Module` responds to all methods defined in `Module`. Of course, here, that still doesn't work, because `attr_accessor` is private.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `attr_accessor` is defined in the class `Module` ([Module#attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)), but how does one go about finding it in the first place? Having to ask someone, or perhaps Googling, is not a very efficient way of going about it.

We can make use of the method [Method#owner](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-owner).<sup>1</sup>

`owner` responds to method objects (instances of the class `Method`), not to method names, which are symbols. Why? Because many modules/classes have methods that have the same symbolic name. For example, `String`, `Array` and `Hash` all have an instance method named `:[]`. Therefore, we cannot ask Ruby where `:[]` is defined. We can ask, however, where the method

```
m = [1,2,3].method(:[])
  #=> #<Method: Array#[]
```

is defined, namely,

```
m.owner
  #=> Array
```

The determination of `m` makes use of the method [Object#method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method).

Alternatively, we could write

```
m = Array.instance_method(:[])
  #=> #<UnboundMethod: Array#[]>
m.owner
  #=> Array
```

This makes use of the method [Module#instance_mathod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_method).

Notice that in the first case the method `:[]` is *bound* to the instance of `Array` `[1,2,3]`, whereas in the second case `:[]` is not bound to any particular instance of `Array`, so it is referred to as `UnboundMethod`. Either way, we see that `Array#[]` is defined in `Array` (i.e., it is not inherited from an ancestor).

Let's consider another example.

We know that `3.zero? #=> false`, but do not find an instance method `:zero?` in the class [Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html). So, where is it? We can write:

```
m = 3.method(:zero?)
  #=> #<Method: Integer(Numeric)#zero?>
```

or

```
m = Integer.instance_method(:zero?)
  #=> #<UnboundMethod: Integer(Numeric)#zero?>
```

then

```
m.owner
  #=> Numeric
```

Aha! It's defined in `Numeric`, the superclass of `Integer`, `Float`, `Rationale` and `Complex`.

Notice that, in computing `m`, the message displayed includes, `"Integer(Numeric)"`. Even before computing `m.owner` this tells us that the owner is `Numeric`. By contrast, in finding the owner of `Array#[]` the message was simply `"Array"`. Helpful as always, Ruby parenthetically gives the owner when the owner is not the class of the receiver of `method` or the class that is the receiver of `instance_method`.

So now let us find the owner of the class method `:attr_accessor`. We know that this method is available for every class (e.g., `Class.new.methods.include?(:attr_accessor) #=> true`), so we could write, say,

```
m = Class.method(:attr_accessor)
  #=> #<Method: Class.attr_accessor>
m.owner
  #=> Module
```

since `Class` is itself a class, but we could have instead written, say,

```
m = Regexp.method(:attr_accessor)
  #=> #<Method: Regexp.attr_accessor>
m.owner
  #=> Module
```

or even

```
m = Class.instance_method(:attr_accessor)
  #=> #<UnboundMethod: Class(Module)#attr_accessor>
m.owner
  #=> Module
```

the last because methods of every class (which is an instance of `Class`) are instance methods of `Class`.

<sup>1 If one forgets where the instance method `owner` is defined, just remember that it is defined on methods, which are instances of the class `Method`.</sup>

Comment: Hi Cary, Thanks for the detailed response. By the way `Class.new.methods.include?(:attr_accessor)` returns `false`, not `true`. Or at least it does in my version of ruby `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32]` I remember testing this myself before posting here.